# Update using a subquery with aggregates and groupby in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to update a column in a table with the max value of that column grouped by another column.

So for example, say we have a table named transactions with two columns: `quantity` and `item_name`. And for whatever reason we want to set `quantity` equal to the maximum `quantity` found for each `item_name`.

I'm pretty stumped and bad at doing things like this in SQL, but here's what I have so far:

```
UPDATE transactions 
SET
quantity = subquery.quantity
FROM (select max(quantity), item_name
      from transaction group by item_name) AS subquery
WHERE  and item_name = subquery.item_name;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to your syntax errors that @Gordon already pointed out, it is regularly a good idea to **exclude empty updates**:

```
UPDATE transaction t
SET    quantity = sub.max_quantity
FROM  (
   SELECT item_name, max(quantity) AS max_quantity
   FROM   transaction
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
WHERE t.item_name = sub.item_name
AND  t.quantity IS DISTINCT FROM sub.max_quantity;
```

No need to write new row versions (at almost full cost) without changing anything. (Except if you want to fire a trigger.)

Comment: Nailed it, thanks! And I like that distinct at the end, thats pretty awesome

Comment: @Gus: I assume you only have one table `transaction` - there were two variants in your original: `transactions`, `transaction`. I picked the singular variant, because I prefer those for table names.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually quite close:

```
UPDATE transactions 
    SET quantity = subquery.quantity
    FROM (select max(quantity) as quantity, item_name
          from transactions
          group by item_name
         ) subquery
    WHERE transactions.item_name = subquery.item_name;
```

I just removed the `and` in `where and` and renamed the table in the subquery to `transactions`.

Comment: Sorry about the typos. I'm getting an issue right now where its telling me subquery.quantity doesn't exist

Comment: @Gus . . . Missed that one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should also work for you. It would evaluate the quantity for each and every row and may be slower than Gordon's answer.

```
UPDATE transactions 
SET quantity = (SELECT MAX(quantity) 
                 FROM transaction as t 
                 WHERE t.item_name = transactions.item_name)
```

Comment: Correlated subueries are generally much more expensive in this context.