# PostgreSQL update table with average vale from another table

Tags: postgresql

I have tried this three different ways and PostgreSQL still doesn't like that I am "aggregate functions are not allowed in UPDATE". I am not sure how to this without doing that. Can someone point me in the right direction to populate my average Wage field with my average wages?

Attempt 1:

```
UPDATE public."JobCategory"
    SET "AverageWage" = round(avg("Wage"), 4)
FROM public."Employees" WERE "Wage" > 0
```

Attempt 2:

```
UPDATE public."JobCategory" c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT round(avg("Wage"), 4) as average
  FROM public."Employees"
) x ON c."Index" = x."JobIndex"
SET c."AverageWage" = x.average
```

Attempt 3:

```
UPDATE public."JobCategory" AS v 
SET "AverageWage" = s.round(avg("Wage"), 4)
FROM public."Employees" AS s
WHERE v."Index" = s."JobIndex"
```

Comment: This answer might be closely related, https://stackoverflow.com/a/22205793/5781248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a subquery:

```
WITH subq AS (
    SELECT round(avg(Wage), 4) as average
    FROM public.Employees
)
UPDATE public.JobCategory jc
SET AverageWage = subq.average
FROM subq
```